# Wordpress show only on posts

Tags: php, wordpress

i have a problem with my WP function. I need it to ONLY be shown on blog posts. Right now it get shown on the other pages such as the frontpage.

Here is my function in functions.php:

```
    function my_sp_function( $content ) {
        $include = FALSE;
        $post = FALSE;

        if ( in_category( array( 3, 4, 5, 6, 91, 133 ) ) ) {

            $include = TRUE;

        }
        if (get_post_type(get_the_ID()) == 'post'){
            $post = TRUE;
        }

        if ( $post = TRUE AND $include == TRUE ) {
                return $content;
        }
}
```

Anybody there knows what i do wrong?

I have tried with this code now, it still shows the $content on the front page..

```
function my_sp_function( $content ) {
        $include = FALSE;
        $post = FALSE;

        if ( in_category( array( 3, 4, 5, 6, 91, 133 ) ) ) {

            $include = TRUE;

        }

        if( is_home() || is_front_page() ) {
        $include = FALSE;
        }

        if ( $post == TRUE AND $include == TRUE ) {
                return $content;
        }
}
```

Comment: Where's the hook? You have to be calling it somehow...that'll be the key.

Comment: You only need to echo my_sp_function(); on single.php, index.php or another post page. You shouldn't call it on any other template file (if used in header/footer/sidebars, use conditional if(is_single() || in_category($cat) || is_category($cat) || etc || etc)).

Comment: Change `if ( $post = TRUE ...` to `if ( $post == TRUE ...`

Comment: if(is_single() || in_category($cat) || is_category($cat) ||.. in my function or what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you would like to include your function only on the home page you have two options - only insert the function into the `single.php` template in your theme, or the prefered method is to only hook your function to `the_content` when [`is_single()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_single) is true but [`is_page()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_page) is false.

```
function my_sp_function( $content ) {
    $content .= "Some more stuff for the_content!";
    return $content;
}
if ( is_single() && ! is_page() ){
    add_filter( 'the_content', 'my_sp_function' );
}
```